# Not able to boot mac osx 64 bit from GRUB version 2.02

Tags: dual-boot

I'm having some trouble booting **Mac OS X** from **GNU GRUB 2.02**.
I get an infinite purple screen when attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I had the exact same problem you are using refind right?  If not hold option when booting load on OS X go here: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ Installing this will allow you to select os x or ubuntu at power on.

This is a workaround:

***Using OS X***

1. Simply click here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.8.3/refind-bin-0.8.3.zip/download to download the rEFInd program/app
2. Unzip the file
3. Open a terminal and goto the location where you unzipped the file ie say you unzipped the file in the Downloads directory you would type `cd Downloads`, then type `./install.sh` this will place the refind on your hard drive.
4. Reboot and refind will give you the options to select how you want to boot.

Comment: rEFInd is also installable by [its PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rodsmith/+archive/ubuntu/refind/+packages), according to these instructions: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#ppa - @daniel including instructions in your post will help people looking at your question, as if the link stops working this answer would become useless.

Comment: From the OP, it seems like he's booting past grub to the Plymouth screen, but the splash is solid purple and the system hangs there. I don't think rEFInd will fix this.

Comment: Well refind loads before grub.  He will be able to choose os x prior to the grub screen.  I never got OS X to load from the grub screen.

Comment: I misread, sorry. Didn't realize he was trying to boot into OS X from grub.

Answer (score 2):

Adding something like

> `menuentry "OS X" {
>       insmod hfsplus
>       set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
>       chainloader /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi }`

to your grub config might help.

> Note that you may need to change the partition number from "gpt3" to something else, such as "gpt2" or "gpt4". You want to identify the partition on which OS X is installed and use its partition number. To use this example, copy it to your /etc/grub.d/40_custom file in Linux and then type sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

I pasted most of this answer from here: [Mac OS X won't boot from grub menu in Ubuntu Precise on Apple MBA(5,2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179689/mac-os-x-wont-boot-from-grub-menu-in-ubuntu-precise-on-apple-mba5-2)